Get all WordPress-created sub folders in uploads directory
I'm writing a maintenance script for my own sites and one part is to clear out all .webp files, since my host now handles WebP conversion on the fly. I could easily traverse through all the sub-folders in the /uploads/ directory, however there's usually other folders in there created by plugins. Is there a way to get a list of only the year/month folders that WordPress created?
I know I can just validate the folder names to check if they're a 4 digit year, I'd just rather do this the "proper" way if it's available.

You can use this WP function wp_get_upload_dir to know the uploads directory path.
Please note different website can choose not to use "year/month" fashion folder structure so using this function we will be advisable.
And then for finding all webp file you can use FileSearchIterator of PHP
$fileScanner = new FileSearchIterator( UPLOAD_BASE_PATH, true, 
        array('webp'));

foreach($fileScanner as $file)
{
    unlink(UPLOAD_BASE_PATH.$file);
}

Note: Code is not tested but hope this should work
